# Creating a graph that represents the timeline of stages

Tags: python, graph

I have the following structure:

```
[
  [
    {
      "build": {
        "end_time": 1633816733,
        "start_time": 1633816697
      }
    },
    {
      "test": {
        "end_time": 1633816797,
        "start_time": 1633816897
      }
    },
    {
      "run": {
        "end_time": 1633816997,
        "start_time": 1633817197
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "build": {
        "end_time": 1633816713,
        "start_time": 1633816612
      }
    },
    {
      "test": {
        "endt_time": 1633816717,
        "start_time": 1633816812
      }
    },
    {
      "run": {
        "end_time": 1633816917,
        "start_time": 1633817113
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Each item in the main array contains a test I made for the benchmarking. It contain an array of stages and the time of each stage. There could be more than three stages (`build,test,run`).

I want to create the following graph (the graph does **not** represent the data above):

[image]

Basically, each line represents the stage time. For example, the first stage is `build` and it the length of the line is `start_time-end_time` but respectively to each other. In other words, the X axis represents the time but the duration so and respectively to the other stages. All of them start on the same point. For example for `build` we get `36` (first test) and `101` (second test) so the length of `build` line of the first test is shorter than the second one. The X axis value does not matter, it just needs to represent the length.

I'm usually using `matplotlib` module in Python to create graph but I could not find something similar in the docs. How do I create such graph using Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [[{'build': {'end_time': 1633816733, 'start_time': 1633816697}}, {'test': {'end_time': 1633816797, 'start_time': 1633816897}}, {'run': {'end_time': 1633816997, 'start_time': 1633817197}}], [{'build': {'end_time': 1633816713, 'start_time': 1633816612}}, {'test': {'end_time': 1633816717, 'start_time': 1633816812}}, {'run': {'end_time': 1633816917, 'start_time': 1633817113}}]]
colors = {'build':'b', 'test':'g', 'run':'r'}
for i, a in enumerate(data, 1):
   x, p = 20, []
   for j in a:
      p.extend([(x, x+(d:=abs(([*j.values()][0]['end_time'] - [*j.values()][0]['start_time'])))), (i, i), colors[[*j.keys()][0]]])
      x += d + 20
   plt.plot(*p)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]